# JavaScript : Elegant way to convert local timezone date object to UTC timezone date object

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, timestamp

I want to convert `Date` object with local timestamp to `Date` "object" with UTC timestamp. One of the methods I have found is as follows:

```
var d = new Date();                  //gives Date object with local timezone
var s_str_utc = d.toUTCString();     //converts it to UTC timezone but 
                                     //is no longer an object but a string
```

Is there a function to convert directly to object instead. I can always use regex and other stuff to get date and time from `s_str_utc`but that wont be an elegant way of doing it.

Comment: I encourage you to try the momentjs library to handle dates in javascript: http://momentjs.com/ Dates handling in javascript is just a nightmare.

Comment: `Date` objects always contain UTC times. `toString()` shows the local version of the UTC time, but internally it's always UTC.

Comment: Ended up using moment.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://momentjs.com/

```
var moment = require("moment");
var d = moment(newDate);
var utc = d.utc();
```